# Integrating SDWebImage to TVOs project

Tags: ios, git, swift, sdwebimage, tvos

I am struggling with how to add `SDWebImage` to a `TVOs` project which i am writing in `swift` language.

I Know there is this commit https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/pull/1327 but what are the steps to integrate that in my project. Currently i have just copied SDWebImage, Vendors and WebImage directories to my project from the above link. I can't do `import SDWebImage` is there some settings that i need to take care of them in my project. Any help will be highly appriciated

Comment: Is there any build settings or flags that i need to add or just copy the source files will work?

Comment: The easiest way would be to use [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org) which supports tvOS 

Comment: Is there a cocoapod for TVOs?

Comment: yes.. you just need to configure your `podfile` properly see [here](http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-0.39/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SDWebImage SDK for TVOs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33391674/sdwebimage-sdk-for-tvos)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a bridging header and import the required headers of SDWebImage to make the respective methods available throughout your swift project.

You can follow this link to create a bridging header :
http://www.learnswiftonline.com/getting-started/adding-swift-bridging-header/

Once the bridging header is created, Add the import statements:

```
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"
#import "UIButton+WebCache.h"
```

You should be able to call the SDWebImage methods of UIImageView and UIButton after this.

For instance to set the image for a imageview :

```
let previewImage : UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,50,50))
previewImage.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: "Your image URL"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "Placeholder")
```